# xinput settings are randomly lost

Tags: linux, xorg, xinput

I start the following script at KDE startup to configure my Logitech TrackMan for left-handed use:

```
#!/bin/bash

lsusb | grep 'Logitech, Inc. Marble Mouse' &>/dev/null || exit 0

xinput set-button-map "Logitech USB Trackball" 3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 9
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "libinput Accel Speed" 1.0
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0 0 1
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "libinput Button Scrolling Button" 9
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 40
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Trackball" "libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled" 0
```

For quite some years, this worked without any problem. But for some months now, randomly, without any pattern I could recognize yet, the `libinput Accel Speed` setting is lost. Alas, I didn't notice this at some exact update (because I also use a "normal" mouse), so I can't tell if with some version of something, it worked, and from some version of something on, this happens.

Interestingly, the other settings persist (like the button mapping etc.). It's only the cursor speed which is reset, e.g. after a wakeup from suspend to disk, after the screen was turned off due to inactivity – or even whilst using the machine.

No other input device is being plugged or unplugged. `dmesg` does not contain anything about an input device reset.

Thanks for all help or explaining this … I'm a bit puzzled about this …